# Schedule Lambda from another Lambda

Tags: java, aws-lambda, aws-lambda-layers, aws-lambda-containers

I have two lambda function and both written in Java. Assume A & B.. When A function got successfully executed then I want B function to be executed after 24 hours.
Is it possible to achieve? If yes how?

Comment: AWS Step Functions is the 'correct' way to wait for a period before invoking an AWS Lambda function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are multiple ways to achieve this using AWS resources. Here are a few options that can be implemented easily:

**Step Functions:** In Step Functions, you can utilize the [Wait](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/step-functions/latest/dg/amazon-states-language-wait-state.html) state to control the transition of messages from one Lambda function to another. By configuring appropriate wait times, you can achieve the desired delay between the execution of Lambda function A and Lambda function B.

**SQS:** Another approach is to trigger Lambda function B using SQS messages. However, note that the [maximum visibility timeout](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSSimpleQueueService/latest/SQSDeveloperGuide/sqs-visibility-timeout.html) for SQS is limited to 12 hours. To achieve a 24-hour window, you can enable the retry functionality on the SQS. However, in order to trigger the retries, you would need to configure Lambda function B to throw an exception during the first attempt of processing the messages from the SQS queue. This will signal to SQS that the message processing should be retried.

Comment: step function is a great solution!

Answer (score 0):

Your lambda A can publish a message in SQS, then your lambda B can be executed each one hour (using Cloudwatch event bridge) and reading the messages in the SQS queue, if a message is detected and have 24 hours published you can continue with the execution of the lambda B and delete the message from SQS.